# Python3.6 - saving big array to file

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, file, pickle

I want to save big array to file. I used `pickle.dump(array, file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)`. It works with small array but when I try to save very big array (e.g. 1GB or more), it uses whole memory and my pc freezes.

Is there any way how to save that big array?

Array example:

```
[[array([1,2,3,298,299,300], dtype=float32),array([1,2,3,298,299,300], dtype=float32),array([1,2,3,298,299,300], dtype=float32)],
 [array([1,2,3,298,299,300], dtype=float32),array([1,2,3,298,299,300], dtype=float32),array([1,2,3,298,299,300], dtype=float32)],
 [array([1,2,3,298,299,300], dtype=float32),array([1,2,3,298,299,300], dtype=float32),array([1,2,3,298,299,300], dtype=float32)]]
```

Comment: maybe saving an array could be done as binary format instead, even if it's a bigger effort. have you an example of `array` (small one please?) I'm not sure of the type.

Comment: Assuming you use `numpy`: Try [`numpy.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html), which saves to a `.npy` file.

Comment: Please give an example of your array.

Comment: Do not use pickle (to store data): http://www.benfrederickson.com/dont-pickle-your-data/ Use Json, Csv, HDF5, ...

Answer (score 0):

If it is (or can be converted into) a numpy array then [numpy.save](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) is more efficient

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the HDF5 format and the python implementation h5py.

http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/quick.html

This makes it possible to append to the file. You can loop over your data set. Or append data in clusters.

```
import h5py

# data
n = int(1e6)
arr = np.arange(n)

# writing to hdf5
f = h5py.File("mytestfile.hdf5", "w")
dset = f.create_dataset("data_name", shape=(n,))
dset[:n] = arr[:n]

f.close()

# reading from hdf5
f = h5py.File("mytestfile.hdf5", "r")
print(f["name"][:])

# outputs
# [      0.       1.       2. ...,  999997.  999998.  999999.]
```